# Why does react component do not re render after changing state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

index.js

```
const [todo, setToDo] = useState([]);
useEffect(async() => {
socket.on("receive_message", (message) => {
  let result = todos ? todos : [];
  if (message.sendBy === 'user') {
    let old_index;
    if (result.length > 0) {
      old_index = result.findIndex(item => item.id === message.senderId);
      if (0 >= result.length) {
        var k = 0 - result.length + 1;
        while (k--) {
          result.push(undefined);
        }
      }
      result.splice(0, 0, result.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
      setTodos(result); // for testing
  }]
});  }, [todos]);

const render =
todos &&
todos.map((item) => {
  return (
    <li
      key={item.id}
      className={activeId.id === item.id ? "person active-user" : "person"}
      data-chat="person1"
      onClick={(e) => historyAccess(item)}
    >
      <div className="user">
        <img
          src={item.profile_pic ? item.profile_pic : "avatars/12.png"}
          alt="Profile Picture"
        />
      </div>
      <p className="name-time">
        <span className="name">{item.name ? item.name : ""}</span>
        {/* <span className="time">{}</span> */}
      </p>
    </li>
  );
});
```

useEffect is working fine and settodos is changing its value as array of objects but it does not re render. It is working absolutely fine and setTodos is changing it's value and working as expected then Why this is happening

Comment: What does your component return? Also this code contains errors and isn't even runnable. Effects can't be `async` themselves they can only call async functions. And your state is inconsistently named sometimes `todo` and sometimes `todos` and the same with `setToDo` and `setTodos`.

Comment: Is this the full file? I do not think so. Show the full file so we can see how the JSX is used. Right now your `const render =` is not returned or anything. Did you use create-react-app or how did you set up the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

[Array.prototype.splice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) mutates the array in-place. You save a reference of your `todos` state to local variable `result` and then mutate it and save it back into state. The array reference never changes.

Also, `useEffect` hook callbacks can't be `async`.

## Solution

1. Shallow copy the array first, then mutate it. This is so React can reconcile that the state has actually updated.
2. Since you don't `await` anything it's safe to remove the `async` declaration

Code:

```
const [todos, setToDo] = useState([]); // <-- todos is already initially defined

useEffect(() => {
  socket.on("receive_message", (message) => {
    const result = [...todos]; // <-- shallow copy todos

    if (message.sendBy === 'user') {
      ...
      result.splice(0, 0, result.splice(old_index, 1)[0]); // <-- then mutate
      setTodos(result);
    }
  });
}, [todos]);
```